# Search maven artifacts by sha1 hash

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Nexus Maven repos can search for maven artifacts based on their sha1 hash:

```
http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=1:<sha1-hash>&rows=20&wt=json
```

I would like to do the same within a custom maven plugin I'm developing. 
Does a maven (java) API exist to search / resolve artifacts by their hash?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not using a repository manager which already supports such things?

Comment: That's probably evident if one knows it :o) I tried to figure out how to do this browsing maven plugins source code such as this: https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer/blob/master/indexer-examples/indexer-examples-basic/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/indexer/examples/BasicUsageExample.java. I did not find documentation and half of the examples I found use deprecated code and methods. Finally I managed to download an index from central repo and to perform the lucene search using an org.apache.maven.index.Indexer.

Comment: Are you looking for something that can tell you if you have an artifact with the same sha1 in your local file system?  Or in a specific maven repository on the internet?